# How to draw Shape exclusively inside Canvas

Tags: .net, wpf, canvas, drawing, shapes

I have a Shape inside [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx), like this:

```
<ScrollViewer>

    <Border Height="342" Width="470" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black">

        <Canvas Background="White">
            <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" Canvas.Left="103" 
                Canvas.Top="186" Fill="Red" />
        </Canvas>

    </Border>

</ScrollViewer>
```

Even if the Rectangle is a Canvas children it's draw outside Canvas limits, covering Border  bottom border. How can I make the Rectangle is draw only inside Canvas limits, ensuring that the part of rectangle that lies beyond is not displayed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what the [ClipToBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx) property was made for:

```
<Canvas Background="White" ClipToBounds="True"> 
    <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" Canvas.Left="103" Canvas.Top="186" Fill="Red" /> 
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, this concise answer helped me fix a longstanding bug in my app.